# Custom ModRewrite to redirect to controller method

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart

I am currently using Alipay which POSTs responses to my OpenCart website URL [on success] that is this `http://192.168.16.58:8080/index.php?route=api/order/callback`.

However, one condition for Alipay is that it stops reading the URL after the `?` separator, so instead of POSTing data to my `route`, it instead `POST`s to `http://192.168.16.58:8080/index.php`

Because of this, I am interested in using RewriteEngine to write a custom rule where when I set the `notify_url` as `http://192.168.16.58:8080/index.php/api/order/callback`, it actually redirects to `http://192.168.16.58:8080/index.php?route=api/order/callback`

What I have is the following:

`RewriteRule ^index.php/api/order/callback.$ index.php?route=api/order/callback [L]`

My logic is that if Alipay is going to `index.php/api/order/callback`, I would instead be redirected to `index.php?route=api/order/callback`, however, using both GET and POST, I am instead redirect to my OpenCart homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^api/order/callback$ index.php?route=api/order/callback [L]`

This would enable:

`http://192.168.16.58:8080/api/order/callback`

to:

`http://192.168.16.58:8080/index.php?route=api/order/callback`